# How to generate a random dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, random

I need to create a dictionary with key and random values given a scope, i.e.

```
{key 1: value1, key 2: value2, key 3: value1, key 4: value 1, key 5: value 1}
```

or

```
{key 1: value2, key 2: value1, key 3: value1, key 4: value 1, key 5: value 1}
```

or

```
{key 1: value1, key 2: value1, key 3: value1, key 4: value 1, key 5: value 2}
```

...and so on

As you can see, the dictionary has the pattern below:

- the key is generated from the input number of the function, if I input 5, I have 5 keys, if I input 3, I have 3 keys
- the value has only 2 different values (`value1` and `value2`), but `value2` can only appear 1 time randomly in any key. The remaining values will be `value1`.

Code:

```
def function(n):
   from random import randrange
   mydict = {}
   for i in range(5):
         key = "key " + str(i)

   value = ['value1', 'value2']
```

Comment: Is there any constraint on the number of key-value pairs that will be present in the dict?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just default all the values to `value1` first, and then randomly pick one key to change to `value2`:

```
def function(n):
   from random import randrange
   values = ['value1', 'value2']
   mydict = {"key " + str(i): values[0] for i in range(n)}
   mydict["key " + str(random.randrange(n))] = values[1]

   return mydict
```

Comment: @Idlehands The OP hasn't mentioned the total number of key-value pairs to be generated.

Comment: @taurus05 The number of keys would be dynamic based on description, but the constraint is that there will always be two values, and only one of them will be `value2`.  If the conditions are changed we can revisit this solution.

Comment: Thanks. I made some changes and now it works!!

def function(n):
    from random import randrange
    import random

    mydict = {}
    mydict = {"key " + str(i): 'value1' for i in range(1,n+1)}
    mydict["key "+ str(random.randrange(1,n+1))] = 'value2'
    return mydict

Comment: You could also just use `str(random.randrange(n)+1)` as well :)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply try this:

```
>>> def func(n):
...   mydict = {}
...   for i in range(n):
...     mydict['key'+str(i)] = randrange(10)
...   return mydict
... 
>>> print(func(5))
{'key0': 8, 'key1': 2, 'key2': 4, 'key3': 4, 'key4': 7}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the fastest way would be to use the built-in [`dict.fromkeys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) classmethod to create a dictionary full of `value1` entries and then randomly change one of them.

```
import random

def function(n):
   mydict = dict.fromkeys(("key "+ str(i) for i in range(n)), 'value1')
   mydict["key "+ str(random.randrange(n))] = 'value2'  # Change one value.
   return mydict

print(function(3))  # -> {'key 0': 'value1', 'key 1': 'value1', 'key 2': 'value2'}
print(function(5))  # -> {'key 0': 'value2', 'key 1': 'value1', 'key 2': 'value1', 'key 3': 'value1', 'key 4': 'value1'}
```

Comment: Is `fromkeys` more efficient than a dict comprehension? Genuinely curious.

Comment: @Idlehands: I haven't actually timed the two, but `fromkeys()` is written in C, so is likely faster. Using Python's built-ins whenever possible is often a good way to improve performance.

Comment: You piqued my interest, so I timed it.  For a dict generation of 100 keys with `n=1000000` trial, the performance between `fromkeys` (53.68s) and dict comp (54.38s) are relatively comparable.  IIRC comprehensions uses C code too so it should be similar.

Comment: @Idlehands: I guess that doesn't surprise me too much in this particular case because it's still generating the keys iteratively using user-supplied (i.e. relatively-slow interpreted) Python code.

Answer (score 1):

similar to @Idlehands, but parametrized for n and actually returns the dict

```
def function(n):
    from random import randrange, randint
    mydict = {'key'+str(i):'value1' for i in range(n)}
    mydict['key'+str(randint(0,n-1))] = 'value2'
    return mydict

print(function(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not terribly clear to me, but I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
   from random import randrange
   mydict = {}
   value = ['value1', 'value2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5']

   for i in range(5):
         key = "key " + str(i)
         mydict.update(key: value[i])
```

Your list either has to be 5 values long (or more) or your for loop has to iterate only twice.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a `dict` comprehension and `numpy.random`:

```py
def create_dict(size=5):
    values = ['value_1', 'value2']

    # choose our index randomly
    x = lambda x: np.random.randint(1, len(values)+1)

    # the 1 in x() is a dummy input var
    return {"key %d"%i: values[x(1)] for i in range(size)}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are already a few options, but this is what I came up with:

```
import random
def my_function(n):
    mydict = {}
    value2_index = random.randint(0, n-1)
    for i in range(n):
        key = "key " + str(i)
        if i == value2_index:
            value = ['value2']
        else:
            value = ['value1']
        mydict.update({key: value})
    return mydict
thing = my_function(5)
print(thing)
```

It's not the cleanest or most beautiful, but I think it makes sense and is easily readable!

Running it once gave me:

> {'key 3': ['value1'], 'key 4': ['value1'], 'key 2': ['value1'], 'key 1': ['value2'], 'key 0': ['value1']}

Answer (score 0):

```
def randDict(n):
    from random import randint

    keys  = ["key"+str(i) for i in range(n)]
    values = ["value"+str(i) for i in range(n)]
    final_dict={}
    for key in keys:
        final_dict[key]=values.pop(randint(0,n))

    return final_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also increase another wrinkle of randomness as shown below:

```
from random import randint, sample

def pseudo_rand_dict(n):
    d = dict()
    r = randint(n, n ** n)
    for i in range(n):
        d[f'key_{i}'] = r
    to_change = sample(d.keys(), 1)[0]
    d[to_change] = randint(n, n * r)
    return d

d = pseudo_rand_dict(5)

print(d)

{'key_0': 2523, 'key_1': 2523, 'key_2': 2523, 'key_3': 9718, 'key_4': 2523}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pick a number first, and then use a dict comprehension to generate the desired dict with values based on whether the index is equal to the picked number or not:

```
def function(n):
    pick = randrange(n)
    return {'key %d' % i: ('value1', 'value2')[i == pick] for i in range(n)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun:

```
import random
n = 4
v1, v2 = 1, 2
res = dict(zip([ f"key{n}" for n in [x for x in range(1,n+1)] ], [ f"value{n}" for n in sorted([v1 for _ in range(n-1)] + [v2], key=lambda k: random.random()) ]))
```